# Disadvantage of giving SYS_ADMIN to Docker container

Tags: docker

I need to add the SYS_ADMIN capability to container so that able to bind mount within container. 
But I have security concerns (please refers to https://lwn.net/Articles/486306/ and  https://rhelblog.redhat.com/2016/11/30/container-tidbits-adding-capabilities-to-a-container/).
If there is actual example about side effects of adding the SYS_ADMIN capability to container?
Another question is, I have heard one can break out from container which has SYS_ADMIN capability to host. But how to achieve it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Note that giving a process SYS_ADMIN capability is pretty close to removing all isolation from it. As a rule, you shouldn’t do this, but it’s helpful to know that you can if you absolutely need to for some reason.

Also, using the `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` command grants a smaller subset of capabilities to the container, compared to the `--privileged` switch, so it’s better to use whenever possible. Try using `--cap-add` and see if that provides the access you need.